# Creating a variable length 2-D arrays in iOS

Tags: ios

Normall, a fixed 2-D arrays in XCode would be like this

```
   NSMutableArray * myBig2dArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // first internal array
 NSMutableArray * internalElement = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
 [internalElement addObject:@"First - First"];
 [internalElement addObject:@"First - Second"];
 [myBig2dArray addObject:internalElement];

    // second internal array
    internalElement = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [internalElement addObject:@"Second - First"];
    [internalElement addObject:@"Second - Second"];
    [myBig2dArray addObject:internalElement];
```

But How do I create variable length 2D array?
I don't the length of each indiviudal array and I don't know how many totoal internal arrays I needed. It's all based on the need

So how do I create that?

Oh one more thing, I need to be able to address individual internal arrays, internal1, internal2, ...etc like that.  Because each one holds a set of elements that share certain commonalities.  I don't want to pile everything inside the big array.

Answer (score 0):

You are already creating a variable length two-dimensional array because you are using NSMutableArray rather than NSArray throughout your example.

This means that you can call:

- addObject: to append an object to the end of an array.
- removeObjectAtIndex: to delete from an array.
- insertObject:atIndex: to insert an item at any location of an array.

Comment: I also have a need of able to address individual internal arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already answered your own question. Just create the main NSMutableArray and then add an inner one whenever you need it. As arrays are mutable you can add any objects to any inner array at any index number of your main or "big" array.

add like this: [[myBig2dArray objectAtIndex:2] addObject:@"someObject"];

remove like this: [[myBig2dArray objectAtIndex:1] removeObjectAtIndex:0];

you just have to make sure that every object of main array is another NSMutableArray

Comment: But I also have a need of able to address individual internal arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code in the question is already the solution.  You refer to the need to address individual internal arrays.  This is just:

```
[[myBig2dArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1];
```

for example.  The new `NSArray` literal syntax makes *look* even more like a two-dimensional array in other languages, e.g.

```
myBig2dArray[1][1];
```

The issue that you are going to have is with disparate internal array sizes.  Therefore, you're going to have to pay attention to the range-checking on the array indices.

Two other suggestions - I'm surprised at how *infrequently* I need to do this.  Almost always there's a better way of structuring the data.  Secondly, if multi-dimensional arrays are really needed, then you may be able to drop down to C to achieve this, depending on what type of data you need to store in the array.  You can create a multidimensional C array of pointers to Objective-C objects.  So long as they are of the same size, and you're willing to deal with `malloc` and `free` memory blocks you can use straight C arrays.